# Pathlib with backlashes within input string

Tags: python, pathlib

I tried to check if a given path exists on Windows/Linux (using `Path.exists()`)

A `FileNotFoundError` is raised on Linux only, obviously when looking at the POSIX path object it is not converted to POSIX.

I would like to know why `pathlib` does not convert the Windows-style path to a POSIX path (currently running on Windows):

```
from pathlib import PosixPath, WindowsPath, Path, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath
raw_string = r'.\mydir\myfile'
print(Path(raw_string))
print(PurePosixPath(raw_string))
```

Output:

```bash
.\mydir\myfile
.\mydir\myfile
```

Both Windows and Linux `pathlib` path imports of the `raw_string` show the same Windows path as the output, and such a Windows path is of course not usable on Linux (second output).

Shouldn't `pathlib` take care of these conversions for `Path` objects to be platform-agnostic?

So that the last output should look like:

```bash
./mydir/myfile
```

Comment: Thanks but I’m looking for a way to use windows formatted paths as is:)(not using even .replace())

Comment: `.\mydir\myfile` is a perfectly valid filename outside of Windows. In most unix filesystems, any bytes other than null and `/` can be part of a filename. That includes ``\``, along with more exotic things like newlines or non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: `Path(PureWindowsPath(raw_string))` works on either platform.
It’s useful if you’re developing on Windows and want to simply copy paste long Windows formatted file paths.

```py
raw_string = r'.\mydir\myfile'
print(Path(PureWindowsPath(raw_string)))
```

Output:

```bash
mydir/myfile
```

And you need the `PureWindowsPath`. If on a Linux system, you just code `print(Path(WindowsPath(raw_string)))` instead, you will get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/11154841) since it is about the needed `PureWindowsPath` if you want to make the Windows path ready for Linux as well.